# What's the best solution to fix a Mac with a liquid damaged and broken keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, apple-silicon, damage

Unfortienaly I spilled some milk on my Macbook Pro M1 2021. I took it to a Mac cleaning service the next day and they cleaned the Mac. Fortunately, the board is not damaged and there was almost no liquid on the board. Everything is functioning as normal except the keyboard. Some keys are acting weird and by looking at the circuit underneath some keys (e.g., right arrow,) I can tell the keyboard is damaged and has some obvious problems and is pretty much done/dead (I'm typing with the keyboard now, but some keys are gone!).

I temporarily got a wireless keyboard to be able to use the Mac until I figure something out. Considering this is a fairly new Mac (I have only for less than a year now,) and the board is not affected, I'm trying to see what would be the best solution to get this Mac back to normal. I wonder if entirely changing the keyboard would be a good or best solution considering the cost and everything? Or can I partially replace only those keys that are not working? Or do you think changing the keyboard is not worth the cost and I should figure something else? And if changing the keyboard is the solution, I wonder if I can find the original keyboard for this Mac? Another problem is that I'm pressed with time, so I'm also looking for a solution that can be done in the sortes amount of time possible.

I know I've asked a lot of questions, but any input or feedback on any of the questions would be helpful.

Comment: I’ve linked the duplicate posts relevant to this.  As for whether or not replacing your keyboard is “worth the cost”, that would be an opinionated position (off topic).  You don’t have a problem with the keys - you have a problem with the electrical traces/contacts *under* the keys.  The whole top case has to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks, @Allan. "whole top case has to be replaced," I think that's what I was looking for, and looks like that is the solution. I was also trying to see if I can find the original top case and if it makes sense for me to sell this Mac and invest in a new one or if replacing the top case would be the most cost-effective solution in my case considering the Mac new and board is not damaged.

Comment: The top case assy includes the battery, so if you replace it, you’ll be refreshing the two most common wear components.   If you keep it, it’ll last for years more.

Comment: I appreciate your response. One last question, is there any way just to replace the keyboard without replacing the battery?

Comment: Technically, yes.  However, it is soooooo labor intensive (a gazillion screws and you have to remove the battery) it’s cheaper and easier to just replace the whole thing.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Allan thanks a million. Very helpful. The only question left is where/if I can find the original Apple top case?

Comment: A 2021 case can be found from authorized service providers or Apple’s own [self service program](https://support.apple.com/self-service-repair)